# Split a matrix block in TikZ into two blocks, is possible or better way to do this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,varwidth,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,matrix,arrows,automata,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, very thick,
  inner sep=2.5pt,
  text centered, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
  text width=4.5cm
  ]
\tikzstyle{block_small} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners,
  very thick, inner sep=2.5pt,
  text centered, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
  text width=2.1cm
  ]
\tikzstyle{block_large} = [draw, rectangle, draw=gray, text=black,
  rounded corners, thin, inner sep=1.5pt,
  minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em, anchor=west, dashed,
  execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{9.4cm}},
  execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}
]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw,circle,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=4mm]
\tikzstyle{connector} = [->,very thick]
\tikzstyle{line} = [very thick]
\tikzstyle{branch} = [circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.3mm,
  fill=black, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{guide} = []
\tikzstyle{snakeline} = [decorate,
     decoration={pre length=0.2cm,
     post length=0.2cm, snake, amplitude=.4mm,
     segment length=2mm},
     thick, gray, -> ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1, auto, >=stealth']
  \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&, row sep=0.5cm, column sep=0.8cm] {
  \node[branch] (u) {}; \\
  \node[block] (B5) {Text here}; \&
  \node[block_large] (C5) {Something to the right of it}; \\
  \node[block_small] (B6) {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.}; \&
  \node[block_small] (D6) {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.}; \&
  \node[block_large] (C6) {Text to the left of it here}; \\
  \node[block] (B7) {Final block}; \&
  \node[block_large] (C7) {Text to the left of it here};  \\
  \node[guide] (D10) {};  \\
  };

  \draw [connector, shorten <=0.5cm] (u) -- node [left] {$x(n)$} (B5);
  \draw [connector] (B5) -- node[left]{$y^{}_\text{s}$} node {Something here} (B6);
  \draw [connector] (B6) -- node[left]{$y^{}_\text{ti}$} node {Something here} (B7);

  \draw [snakeline] (B5) -- node {} (C5);
  \draw [snakeline] (D6) -- node {} (C6);
  \draw [snakeline] (B7) -- node {} (C7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get now this:

[image: Sample output]

I want to get this so basically all the squigly line blocks align properly on the right. The right side of the middle block in the second row lines up with the right side of the the block in the first row. The first block in the second row moves to the left like the red arrow shows. Both blocks in the second row are pointed to by the first block in the first row but only the first block in the second row points to the block in the third row.

[image: Sample final output]

How do I move this down and place text only on the one line before the T:
[image]

Comment: Can you please complete this to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, the code should compile.

Comment: I have made your code compilable and added an image of the output, but it is not clear to me what you want to achieve.  Can you provide some description of the desired output?

Comment: Like Andrew, I don't understand what you want to do, please, explain it better.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Okay I hope I have updated better with a photo at the bottom and description above it of what I want. Sorry for the obscurity in the description.

Comment: @Ignasi Updated the explanation so hope it helps.

Comment: Note that you can't nest tikz matrices (yet - according to the error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, slightly different to *Ignasi* answer. Main features:

- used only two node styles: `block` with option for minimum width and calculation of text width from it, and `block_dash`, which is almost the same as `block_large` in your MWE
- width of top and bottom block is calculated by `veclen` from library `calc`
- for connections between blocks is use `edge` with labels defined by `quotes` syntax
- from code of all lines are removed empty nodes, if there are plans to later add some text in it, then I suggest use edge labels as they are used in connection between nodes `block`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, very thick,
           minimum width=#1, minimum height=2em, inner sep=2.5pt, outer sep=0pt, 
           text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
           align=center},
block_dash/.style = {draw, dashed, rounded corners, thin, 
            inner sep=1.5pt, minimum size=2em,
            execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{88mm}},
            execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}},
 connector/.style = {-stealth',very thick},
 snakeline/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm,
                        pre length=2mm, post length=2mm},
            thick, gray, -stealth'},
            }% end of tikzset

\usepackage{varwidth, mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.1, 
    auto,
    node distance=15mm and 0mm]
\node (B1) [block=21mm]         {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\node (B2) [block=21mm,
            right=22mm of B1]   {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\path   let \p1 = ($(B1.west)-(B2.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (B3) [block=\n1, 
                   above right=of B1.north west]   {Text here}
        node (B4) [block=\n1,%,
         below right=of B1.south west]   {Text here};
%
\draw[connector]    ($(B3.north)+(0,1)$) node[left] {$x(n)$}    -- (B3);
\draw[connector]    
        (B3.south -| B1) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something here"]  (B1)
        (B3.south -| B2) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something here"]  (B2)
        (B1) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something here"]  (B1 |- B4.north);
%
\draw[snakeline]    
        (B2.east) -- + (2,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
\draw[snakeline]    
        (B3.east) -- + (2,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
\draw[snakeline]    
        (B4.east) -- + (2,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Addendum:**
as response to added my code in your question. Your modification is not cewry consistent. Missing are preamble (`\documentclass{...}` and necessary packages), in `\tikzset}...}` are missing a comma after added definition, and added definition contain many surplus options. After correcting this, I rearrange  your modification in correct order of code and add your new requests (I'm not sure, if I understand them correctly). Obtained result is:

[image]

and MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% <-- added for inserting images, had to be before package `tikz`
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <-- in real document remove option `demo`
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
every edge quotes/.style = {% <-- added for writing edge label in more lines
            font=\small\linespread{.8}\selectfont,
            text=black, align=left},
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, very thick,
           minimum width=#1, minimum height=2em, inner sep=2.5pt, outer sep=0pt,
           text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
           align=center},
block_dash/.style = {draw, dashed, rounded corners, thin,
            inner sep=1.5pt, minimum size=2em, text=black,
            execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{9cm}},
            execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}},
block_noborder/.style = {text width=#1, align=left, % <-- renamed and removed surplus options
            text=black, inner sep=1.5pt},
 connector/.style = {-stealth',very thick},
 snakeline/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=1.5mm,
                        pre length=2mm, post length=2mm},
            thick, gray, -stealth'},
              }% end of tikzset

\usepackage{varwidth, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added for correct writing of units

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.1,
    auto,
    node distance=15mm and 0mm]
\node (B31) [block=21mm]         {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\node (B32) [block=21mm,
            right=5mm of B31]   {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\path   let \p1 = ($(B31.west)-(B32.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (B2) [block=\n1,
                   above right=of B31.north west]  {Half-wave Rectifier}
        node (B1) [block=\n1,
                   above=of B2]   {Gammatone and Outer-middle Ear Filter}
        node (B4) [block=\n1,%,
         below right=of B31.south west]   {Text here};
%
\draw[connector]    
    ($(B1.north)+(0,1)$) node[left] {$x(n)$} -- (B1)
    (B1) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]  (B2); 
    \coordinate[below=11mm of B2.south] (B33); % <-- auxiliary coordinates, for orthogonal paths between `box` nodes
    \coordinate[below=4mm of B32.south-|  B4] (B34);
\draw[connector]
        (B2) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]    (B33) -| (B31);
\draw[connector]    (B33) -| (B32);
\draw[connector]
        (B31) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "short\\ text\\ only"]   (B31 |- B4.north)
        (B32) |- (B34) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]   (B4);
%
\draw[snakeline]
        (B32.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here. Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here};
\draw[snakeline] % <-- this part of code is rewrite from scratch
        (B1.east) -- + (0.7,0) node (s1) [block_noborder=0.35\textwidth,right] {%
           \includegraphics[width=\hsize, trim = 1.55cm 1.4cm 0 0, clip] {spectral/figures/FilterResponseMiddleEar.pdf}}
                                node (s2) [block_noborder=0.25\textwidth,right=of s1] {%
                                            $N_c=300$ channels, \\
                                            $f_{\text{s}}^{}=\SI{12000}{Hz}$.};
\draw[snakeline]
        (B4.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2):**

According to (I hope to very) last request I change second example accordingly. Also I take opportunity and change edge label definition. Now the multi line labels has less vertical space between lines.

Comment: I tried using your answer but I couldn't figure out how to get the other blocks to line up correctly above and below the split block. I have like 8 blocks but only those two are split so there is one more block above the split blocks and like 4 blocks below it. None of which are split. I also only want the arrows going down but I was seeing if I could get what I have added in my question where for the split block they leave in the middle and go out at a right angle. Also I want the arrow coming from the right block back into the system as shown but also at a right angle would be best.

Comment: If you check my question I have added a picture and the code I added from your base code. Also I drew a picture to get a better idea of what I want. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: @JSpen, I respond to your edit of questions with addendum to my answer. I'm not sure if I understand your new request well. If you have further request regarding your questions, it will be better to ask them in new question. Your problem will see more people and higher probability to receive more useful answer(s). I believe, that now is time to accept one of received answers as one, which the best answer on your question :) .

Comment: I have figured everything else out on my own for the diagram as there are 5 more blocks except what is shown in the figure. If you think best, I can ask a new question. But I know how to move the line down further where it splits into a T but I can't figure out how to get it so text is only on the top part before it splits instead of on the two side lines.

Comment: I have added a diagram showing your design with the one change in red. Then text on the single line before the split.

Comment: @JSpen, I consider your (very) last wish and accordingly change second example. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

As `matrix` doesn't allow `multicolumn` nodes, it's better to forget it and use `positioning` library.

1.- First two central nodes are placed.
2.- Two fit nodes are used to fix upper and lower nodes size.
3.- As all nodes are right aligned, comments can be easily placed
4.- Perpendicular coordinates `-|` are used to draw vertical lines.
5.- Deprecated `tikzstyle` has been replaced with `tikzset`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, varwidth, mathtools}

\usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows, positioning, decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle, rounded corners, very thick,
            inner sep=2.5pt,
            text centered, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
            text width=4.5cm},
    block_small/.style = {draw, rectangle, rounded corners,
            very thick, inner sep=2.5pt,
            text centered, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em,
            text width=2.1cm},
    block_large/.style = {draw, rectangle, draw=gray, text=black,
            rounded corners, thin, inner sep=1.5pt,
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em, anchor=west, dashed,
            execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{9.4cm}},
            execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}},
    sum/.style = {draw,circle,inner sep=0mm,minimum size=4mm},
    connector/.style = {->,very thick},
    line/.style = {very thick},
    branch/.style = {circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.3mm,
            fill=black, draw=black},
    guide/.style = {},
    snakeline/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={pre length=0.2cm,
            post length=0.2cm, snake, amplitude=.4mm,
            segment length=2mm},
            thick, gray, ->},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1, auto, >=stealth']

    \node[block_small] (B6) {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.}; 
    \node[block_small, right=of B6] (D6) {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.}; 

    \node[block_large, right=2cm of D6] (C6) {Text to the left of it here};

    \node[block, fit=(B6.west) (D6.east), inner xsep=0pt, 
        above right= 1 and 0 of B6.north west, label=center:Text here] (B5) {};
    \node[block_large, right=2cm of B5] (C5) {Text to the left of it here};

    \node[branch, above=of B5] (u) {};

    \node[block, fit=(B6.west) (D6.east), inner xsep=0pt, 
        below right= 1 and 0 of B6.south west, label=center:Text here] (B7) {};
    \node[block_large, right=2cm of B7] (C7) {Text to the left of it here};

    \node[guide, below=of B7] (D10) {};

    \draw [connector, shorten <=0.5cm] (u) -- node [left] {$x(n)$} (B5);
    \draw [connector] (B5.south-|B6) -- node[left]{$y^{}_\text{s}$} node {Something here} (B6);
    \draw [connector] (B5.south-|D6) -- node[left]{$y^{}_\text{s}$} node {Something here} (D6);
    \draw [connector] (B6) -- node[left]{$y^{}_\text{ti}$} node {Something here} (B7.north-|B6);
%
    \draw [snakeline] (B5) -- node {} (C5);
    \draw [snakeline] (D6) -- node {} (C6);
    \draw [snakeline] (B7) -- node {} (C7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```